# How to reserve 'n' characters for TextView content to maintain the related view alignment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-listview, textview

[image]
[image]

Its clear from the above shot, what i mean, i'm certain about the number of subscribers will be around 10 digit max, and i would like to reserve a space for 10 characters so that it doesn't alter the other ImageView [birdy]'s alignment. I'm using relative layout for this this view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the attribute [android:minEms](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3aminEms)

Setting minEms to an integer value say 5, on an EditText or TextView should ensure it's at least 5 characters wide.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing layout_width property from "wrap_content" to something fixed. I would use something like 100dp. I'm not sure if it's a good approach, though.

Answer (score 1):

If you truly want to have the width of a TextView with 10 characters then XXXdp isn't a option. What you could do is measure what a textview with 10 characters width is and use that for (all( the TextViews in you listitem layout.

Comment: Should he measure that in run time?

Comment: Yes. I think you can use this method in the Paint class: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#measureText(java.lang.String)